# How do I make a bunch of different draggable/droppable elements droppable to each other?

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable

I have a bunch of elements(lets say "div A", "div B", and "div C"), and they're all draggable and droppable. They all accept draggable elements from the initial div("div A") that the elements are inside. Then I can drag them back to "div A" if they are in "div B" or "div C".

However I can't figure out how to make it so I can drag from "div B" to "div C", or vice versa. Whenever I try to add that code it just messes everything up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sortable instead of draggable/dropable

Comment: you mean it's impossible with draggable?

Comment: as I understand if you need to move divs around... it suppose to be sortable